# On my 2017 Honda HRV, a blue thermometer light on the dashboard is always on in the morning indicating that the coolant temperature is cold

Tags: honda, coolant, indicators

Maintenance Question.  On my 2017 Honda HRV, a blue thermometer light on the dashboard is always on in the morning indicating that the coolant temperature is cold.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

General note about warning lights: yellow means you should avoid driving the car unnecessarily. Red means you should stop driving the car immediately at the next safe spot, and have it towed. A continuous sound and a red warning light means you should stop immediately, no matter how inconvenient it might be, and have it towed.

Of course, it is normal to see all yellow and red lights turn on for few seconds after starting the car. This is just a test that all lights work.

Green and blue, on the other hand, mean that everything is okay, the light is just telling you about something that might be of interest. In this case, it means that you should avoid hauling ass until the engine is at proper operating temperature. However, the engine management system might already limit engine power somewhat when cold in case you are driving it like you stole the car, so I would just ignore the light.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, its normal. You could refer to your owners manual for more information on it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to our group. I hope you like our responses.

The blue led indication is for coolant temperature. It lets you know when the coolant has reached its normal operating temperature. Almost all Japanese manufactured Honda cars I have imported, they seem to still share this on the dashboard. I usually let the cars warm up until the blue led is lit no more.

When I checked with an obd transmitter, it goes away when the thermostat senses 184° F or close to 90° C

Comment: Is it the black edition you acquired?